# How do you open a specific excel sheet from sharepoint URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

I have an excel with numerous sheets uploaded in sharepoint. How do I create a URL to access the specific sheet. I have referenced similar questions but it goes straight to download instead of going to online sharepoint.

To access the web version, I am able to do this : `/"SpreadsheetName".xlsx?web=1`

What is the URL so I can force it go to Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, etc.?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Copy Link function on the workbook (so that you get a link that looks something like this:)

`https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/sitename/EaPm6BD3KkVJvwjuzQdOrcEBR0YOqbFUWn10YGyL26cMKQ?e=8y1CEl`

You can append **&ActiveCell=Sheet1** at the end and it will open that sheet, in the browser.

The same works if you copy the URL that displays when you have an Excel Workbook open in the browser, that includes `Doc.aspx?` like:

`https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/sitename/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B10E8E6A3-2AF7-4945-BF08-EECD074EADC1%7D&file=Test.xlsx&action=default&mobileredirect=true&cid=2657a1f5-62a5-4d13-8bff-c1771a74f2cb`

---

It does not work when you do a hard link to the document (/sites/sitename/Documents/Test.aspx?web=1) like in your example unfortunately, only when using links like mentioned above.

Comment: "when you have an Excel Workbook open in the browser" this doesn't seem to work.
What will be the format of '&ActiveCell=Sheet1' if there is space in sheet name?

Comment: The format will be the same - spaces will be URL encoded as `%20`