# Open URL hyperlink from excel application or excel online to a specific worksheet

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, excel, online

I'm looking to create hyperlinks from Excel Online/Application to Excel sharepoint files.
After looking throught the forum, I found solutions to create working links :

- From Online App
- From the desktop App

But I can't figure out if there is a solution which is working in both cases.
(Links will be clicked either from on excel online or excel native application)

To fix it temporary, I have made two links to use either for online app or application. But I would like one unique link if possible.

Reference of the thread for online to online link : [How to open a specific excel sheet from sharepoint URL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/278624/how-do-you-open-a-specific-excel-sheet-from-sharepoint-url)

When trying from desktop app, I can open URL links, but it does not bring me to the specified sheet, this is the main issue and why I'm requesting your help.

**Link example :** https://.../.../Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=[filename].xlsx&Activecell='Sheetname'!A1&Action=default&mobileredirect=true

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand that you want to open SharePoint Online excel file sheet in the excel application or excel online.

Per my test, first copy link of excel file in the SharePoint Online, then add &ActiveCell=Sheet1 at the end of link. This link can open SharePoint Online excel file sheet both in the excel application or excel online.

Example：

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/emilytestnew/EeO1zif29clDnX3Sa58zVugB7UqDyT6omhYf3KM-dascgg?e=RACCQr&ActiveCell=Sheet2

Comment: Thanks for your trial, yes it is working, the file open but not on the specific sheet requested. Try to put "&ActiveCell=Sheet3" and save on sheet1, it will open on sheet1 by the link. (At least in my case for now)